# apply style property to ng-bind directive in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

We have created the div using ng-bind directive in angular js. We are not able to apply style property to that same div

```
<div ng-bind-html="test"></div>
```

in contrller file i defined test variable as

```
$scope.test="<div style="background:red;"></div>
```

We need to apply the style property. using CSS property i can able to do. But each time the background needs to be changed.

Comment: Can you show us a fiddle (what version of angular.. assuming and old one?

Comment: Fix your quoting in the controller and try again.

Answer (score 5):

may be wat you want is this:

```
<div ng-style="{'background-color': bgColor}"></div>
```

in your controller

```
$scope.bgColor = "red";
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont know what you want but the only thing wrong with your code is yo uneed `ng-bind-html-unsafe` ... assuming you are using a version of angular < 1.2.

ng-bind-html runs the code through a [`$sanitize`](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ngSanitize.%24sanitize) service, which checks for unsafe code.  In your example I and "style" will be stripped out.  The unsafe version does not perform this check and as a result if you use it in certain situations where you dont have complete control over(e.g. WYSIWYG editors saving to your database and displaying the comments.) the data you can have punks running around doing malicious scripts.

Example fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/pW7WY/

Supporting code.

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
       <div id="nick" ng-bind-html-unsafe="test"></div>
    </div>
</div>


--js
function Ctrl($scope) {
   $scope.test='<div id="child" style="background:red;"></div>'
}

--css
#nick{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
#child{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;      
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is the difference in unsafe and ng-bind-html.

Comment: @ShardulPendse just updated.